# Overriding CSS inline

Tags: css, background, overriding, inline-styles

Part of my stylesheet looks like this:

```
ul#secondary-menu li {
    background: url("images/secondary-menu-bg.png") repeat-y scroll right top transparent;
    padding-right: 2px;
}
```

How do I override the background image inline? I have tried this:

```
<li id="menu-41" class="item-41" style="ul#secondary-menu li { background: none;}"><a href="http://www.test.com">Test</a></li>
```

I also added the `!important` tag but it had no effect. What am I doing wrong here? Note that I am looking for a solution to override the background image **inline**.

Comment: you probably mean `style="background: none;"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inline styles don't have selectors. They are just a set of declarations, so you can remove the selector and the curly braces:

```
<li id="menu-41" class="item-41" style="background: none;"><a href="http://www.test.com">Test</a></li>
```

Comment: Alright, newbie mistake, I will accept this answer in a few minutes when the time limit reaches...

Answer (score 2):

You dont specify selectors inside the inline style tag because those styles apply only to that element.

```
<li id="menu-41" class="item-41" style="background: none;">
```

is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yea you don't need to specify the inline style tag so just make it change the style to `style="background: none;"` and you should be good to go